# Maintaining MQTT published order across shared consumers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

If we consider a scenario with multiple MQTT publishers (each one publishing to a dedicated topic) and we try to consume using multiple consumers on a shared wildcard subscription, it is possible to ensure that messages from the same topic are always handled by the same shared consumer? Would something like https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering achieve this on google pub/sub? Any other broker that can offer this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: The whole point of specific Topics is for specific Subscribers to process the message.  If you have a "pool" of potential Subscribers, but only want one to process a particular Topic, then you need to have some kind of assignment Topic to broadcast the request, nodes respond, and a controller picks and replies back with the one assigned node ID on the assignment Topic.

Comment: Can you share more information about the current use scenario and the other cloud services involved besides Pub/Sub?